# How do i fix the error "TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not list" when making a simple flappy bird game?

Tags: python, pygame

Im following a tutorial on youtube for making a flappy bird game with python and pygame. I have done what he's done so far but when i try to run the code i get an error:

`TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not list`

I really don't know what could be causing the issue.

I have tried googling and found some threads with potenial answers to my question, but because I dont have much experience in python and pygame it's hard for me to understand what other peoples code have in common with mine to fix the problem.

Here is my code:

```
import pygame
import neat
import time
import random
import os

WIN_WIDTH= 600
WIN_HEIGHT= 800

BIRD_IMGS = [pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load("imgs/bird1.png")), pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load("imgs/bird2.png")), pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(("imgs/bird3.png")))]
PIPE_IMG = [pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load("imgs/pipe.png"))]
BASE_IMG = [pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load("imgs/base.png"))]
BG_IMG = [pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load("imgs/bg.png"))]


class Bird:
    IMGS = BIRD_IMGS
    MAX_ROTATION = 25
    ROT_VEL = 20
    ANIMATION_TIME = 5


    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x=x
        self.y=y
        self.tilt = 0
        self.tick_count = 0
        self.velocity = 0
        self.height = self.y
        self.img_count=0
        self.img=self.IMGS[0]

    def jump(self):
        self.vel=-10.5
        self.tick_count = 0
        self.height = self.y

    def move(self):
        self.tick_count +=1

        d = self.vel*self.tick_count + 1.5*self.tick_count**2

        if d >= 16:
            d = 16

        if d < 0:
            d -= 2

        self.y=self.y+d

        if d < 0 or self.y < self.height + 50:
            if self.tilt < sel.MAX_ROTATION:
                self.tilt=self.MAX_ROTATION
        else:
            if self.tilt>-90:
                self.tilt-=self.ROT_VEL

    def draw(self,win):
        self.img_count+=1

        if self.img_count<self.ANIMATION_TIME:
            self.img=self.IMGS[0]
        elif self.img_count<self.ANIMATION_TIME*2:
            self.img=self.IMGS[1]
        elif self.img_count<self.ANIMATION_TIME*3:
            self.img=self.IMGS[2]
        elif self.img_count<self.ANIMATION_TIME*4:
            self.img=self.IMGS[1]
        elif self.img_count==self.ANIMATION_TIME*4+1:
            self.img=self.IMGS[0]
            self.img_count=0 

        if self.tilt <= -80:
            self.img=self.IMGS[1]
            self.img_count=self.ANIMATION_TIME*2

        rotated_image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.img, self.tilt)
        new_rect = rotated_image.get_rect(center=self.img.get_rect(topleft=(self.x, self.y)).center)
        win.blit(rotated_image, new_rect.topleft)

    def get_mask(self):
        return pygame.mask.from_surface(self.img)



((((THIS IS WHERE I GET MY ERROR CODE))))))

def draw_window(win, bird):
HERE--> win.blit(BG_IMG, (0,0))
    bird.draw(win)
    pygame.display.update()

((((ABOVE HERE IS WHERE I GET MY ERROR CODE))))))

def main():
    bird=Bird(200,200)
    win=pygame.display.set_mode((WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT))

    run=True
    while run:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run=False

        draw_window(win,bird)

    pygame.quit()
    quit()

main()
```

Comment: I didn't run the code but looking at the docs maybe you want to use `win=pygame.display.get_surface()` https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.get_surface. I don't think the `set_mode()` method returns a `surface` . So after you set the mode, use `get_surface()` to get the surface

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is caused, because in

> ```py
> win.blit(BG_IMG, (0,0))
> ```

`BG_IMG` is a list with a single element:

> ```py
> BG_IMG = [pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load("imgs/bg.png"))]
> ```

Get the 1st element of the list to solve the issue (`BG_IMG[0]`):

```py
win.blit(BG_IMG[0], (0,0))
```

---

Of course you can make `BG_IMG` a single surface rather than a list of surfaces instead:

```py
BG_IMG = pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load("imgs/bg.png"))
```

---

Further `self.vel = 0` is missing in the constructor of the class `Bird`:

```py
class Bird:
    # [...]

    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.vel = 0
        # [...]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This fixed the problem :) Now i get another error though.. when i write "bird.move()" in this for loop "run=True
 while run:
  for event in pygame.event.get():
   if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
    run=False
  bird.move()
  draw_window(win,bird)"  i get the error "AttributeError: 'Bird' object has no attribute 'vel'"

Comment: @Moreno `self.vel = 0` is missing int the constructor (`__init__`) of the class `Bird`. A bit later there is a typo `self.MAX_ROTATION` rather than `sel.MAX_ROTATION`

Comment: thanks for you taking your time to learn me and being patient, now i don't really understand what you mean when you say im missing the int the constructor. Where am i suppose to write __init__?

Comment: Oh im new to the site but i did all things now. Did you understand my question or did i put the sentence wrong maybe. I am confused of what you mean with "self.vel = 0 is missing int the constructor (__init__) of the class Bird" im sorry if im taking your time.

Comment: @Moreno I've extended the answer. See the last section.

Comment: Thanks so much!! Now i understand :) Thanks for putting up the time and effort into this only to help me. Have a good day/night!